# Mouse hover on plotly graph doesn't show any content when the content is large and doesn't fit in the screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, plotly, plotly-python

Below is my input data (this is ONLY a simpler sample of the actual data, the actuall data is much BIG)

```
LOG_NAME,DATETIME,LOG_CONTENT
Server1.log,2023-03-19T06:39:52,Server1 Log Line1
Server1.log,2023-03-19T06:47:20,Server1 Log Line2
Server1.log,2023-03-19T07:45:15,Server1 Log Line3
Server1.log,2023-03-19T08:30:15,Server1 Log Line4
Server1.log,2023-03-19T09:10:00,Server1 Log Line5
Server2.log,2023-03-19T06:00:01,log for Server2  Line1
Server2.log,2023-03-19T06:15:48,log for Server2  Line2
Server2.log,2023-03-19T06:27:59,log for Server2  Line3
Server2.log,2023-03-19T06:32:59,log for Server2  Line4
Server3.log,2023-03-19T07:35:05,This is Server3 Log Line1
Server3.log,2023-03-19T07:48:45,This is Server3 Log Line2
Server3.log,2023-03-19T07:57:33,This is Server3 Log Line3
Server3.log,2023-03-19T08:16:49,This is Server3 Log Line4
Server3.log,2023-03-19T08:39:14,This is Server3 Log Line5
Server4.log,2023-03-19T07:00:44,Line of Server4 log - 1
Server4.log,2023-03-19T08:43:17,Line of Server4 log - 2
Server4.log,2023-03-19T09:39:19,Line of Server4 log - 3
Server4.log,2023-03-19T10:14:20,Line of Server4 log - 4
Server4.log,2023-03-19T11:40:23,Line of Server4 log - 5
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:28,Line of Server4 log - 6
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:28,Line of Server4 log - 7
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:29,Line of Server4 log - 8
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:30,Line of Server4 log - 9
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:31,Line of Server4 log - 10
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:32,Line of Server4 log - 11
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:33,Line of Server4 log - 12
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:34,Line of Server4 log - 13
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:35,Line of Server4 log - 14
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:36,Line of Server4 log - 15
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:37,Line of Server4 log - 16
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:38,Line of Server4 log - 17
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:39,Line of Server4 log - 18
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:40,Line of Server4 log - 19
Server4.log,2023-03-19T12:20:41,Line of Server4 log - 20
```

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

infile1 = "/tmp/data3.csv"
outfile1 = "/tmp/out3.csv"
outhtml1 = "/tmp/timeline3.html"

columns2 = ['MIN_DATETIME','MAX_DATETIME','LINE_COUNT']
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile1)
df2 = df1.groupby(['LOG_NAME']).agg({'DATETIME': ["min", "max"],'LOG_NAME': ["count"]})
df2.columns = columns2
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(f"df2=\n{df2}")
df1["DATETIME2"] = "[" + df1["DATETIME"] + "]"
df1["DT_LOG_CONTENT"] = df1[["DATETIME2", "LOG_CONTENT"]].apply(":".join, axis=1)
df3 = df1.groupby('LOG_NAME')['DT_LOG_CONTENT'].apply("<br>".join).reset_index()
print(f"df3=\n{df3}")
df3.to_csv(outfile1)
customdata = np.stack((df3['LOG_NAME'], df3['DT_LOG_CONTENT']), axis=-1)
print(customdata)
hovertemp = ('<b>log file:</b> %{customdata[0]}<br>' +
    '<b>log content:</b> %{customdata[1]}<br>')

fig = px.timeline(df2, x_start='MIN_DATETIME', x_end='MAX_DATETIME', y='LOG_NAME', color='LINE_COUNT')
fig.update_traces(customdata=customdata, hovertemplate=hovertemp)
# fig.show()

with open(outhtml1, 'w') as f:
    f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=True))
```

Below is the output chart:
[image]
[image]

Now when the chart is displayed in a small screen, it doesn't show any content on mouse hover over Server4.log (*as the the mouse hover content doesn't fit in the screen*), but it shows data on mouse hover over the other Log Names.
In real time scenario I expect 100+ log lines (*with larger content*) sometimes and in those cases on mouse hover over the specific log name (*with 100+ lines*) no content is displayed as that many log lines doesn't fit in the screen.

**How to solve this issue? anything can be done like adding a vertical scroll bar in the mouse hover output?**